# Bash: String manipulation with sed and Regular expression is not working: replace a string by slash

Tags: regex, sed

I hope you can help me out:

Here is one of my lines that I have to string manipulate:

```
./period/0.0.1/projectname/path/path/-rw-rw-r--filename.txt 2462
```

Where the last number is the file size and needed for later calculations.

The sequence `-rw-rw-r--` is from a file listing Output where I separated files from directories and skipped all lines starting with "d".
Now I need to get rid of the rights sequence in the lines.

Here is my regex, that exactly hits that target: `[/][-][-rwx]{9,9}`
I checked tat with a regex checker and get exact what I want:
the string /- including the following 9 characters.

What I want: replace this string " /- including the following 9 characters " by a single slash /.
To avoid escaping I use pipe as separator in sed. The following sed command is working correct:

```
sed 's|teststring|/|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

The problem:

When I replace "teststring" bei my regex it is not manipulating anything:

```
sed 's|[/][-][-rwx]{9,9}|/|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

I get no errors at all, but have no stringmanipulations in result outputfile.

What am I doing wrong here??

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` uses the [BRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#bre) regex flavour by default, where braces should be escaped.

Either escape them :

```
sed 's|[/][-][-rwx]\{9,9\}|/|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

Or switch to ERE :

```
sed -n 's|[/][-][-rwx]{9,9}|/|g' inputfile > outputfile # for GNU sed
sed -E 's|[/][-][-rwx]{9,9}|/|g' inputfile > outputfile # for BSD sed & modern GNU sed
```

As a side note, your regex can be simplified to `/-[-rwx]{9}` :

```
sed -E 's|/-[-rwx]{9}|/|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed` with extended regex:

```
sed -E 's|/-[-rwx]{9}|/|g' file
```

```
./period/0.0.1/projectname/path/path/filename.txt 2462
```

- No need to use `[/]` and `[-]` in your regex
- Use `-E` for extended regex matching
- `.{9,9}` is same as `.{9}`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
sed 's|/-[-rwx]\{9\}|/|g'
```

Note that in POSIX BRE patterns, in order to specify a limiting quantifier, you need to escape the braces.

See the [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/ll1vMp):

```
s='./period/0.0.1/projectname/path/path/-rw-rw-r--filename.txt 2462'
echo $s | sed 's|/-[-rwx]\{9\}|/|g'
```

Output:

```
./period/0.0.1/projectname/path/path/filename.txt 2462
```

**NOTE**: It is not a good idea to wrap each individual char with a bracket expression, `[/]` = `/` and `[-]` = `-`.